# Render 1000+ shapes in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

How can I render a bunch of hand drawn shapes in opengl 1.x? I know about instancing but how is it possible in old opengl? Could I get examples of some sort? This is for a game, I'm expecting a thousand or so shapes all of which will need to be updated every frame.

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146291/opengl-2d-example-game) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that (at least most of) the shapes remain unchanged from one frame to the next, so most of the update is just moving them around, you could at least consider building a display list for each shape, then rendering the display lists during an update.

The amount of good you'll get from this varies widely depending on the hardware (and possibly driver) in use though. Some hardware supports display lists directly, and gains a lot from it. With other hardware, you'll be hard put to find any difference at all.

The good points are that at worst this won't do any harm, and building/using display lists is pretty quick and easy. So, in the worst case you don't lose much, and in the best case you might gain quite a bit.